# How to easily determine if a function could sleep in the Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

As I understand, inside interrupt context we should not call functions that could sleep.

So, is there a documentation, convention, clues or any easy way to determine if some function in the kernel could sleep?

Answer (score 2):

One major hint is a call to `might_sleep`, which most core kernel functions call as a way of catching bogus callers early on.  You can also look for calls to `schedule` and its variants.

Comment: Second hint is to look for comment for each particular function of interest. It's often stated that function can sleep (if comment is present, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You know if the function can sleep because you know if it can be called from an interrupt context, what guarantees are required when calling it (locks, RCU) and finally you see what it affords to do on its own.

There is no way around reading surrounding code and at least few consumers.

Stuff would be easier if typical code asserted requirements, but that's unfortunately not the case in Linux.